# MDX - Showing dimension value for related item

Tags: ssas, mdx

I've a case if the item has no transaction for the selected date then by standard it'll showing blank value / not showing at all, but I want if there's no measure / transaction at all it'll instead showing the unit price from that item dimension.

I've tried the following script but it's still not showing as i expected. any help?

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Minimum Selling Price custom1]
                                AS 
IIF(
    ISEMPTY
        (
            MIN(PERIODSTODATE([Date].[Date YQMD].[(All)], [Date].[Date YQMD]), [Measures].[Minimum Minimum Sell Price])
        )
        , [Item].[Unit Price]
        , MIN(PERIODSTODATE([Date].[Date YQMD].[(All)], [Date].[Date YQMD]), [Measures].[Minimum Minimum Sell Price])
    ),
    FORMAT_STRING = "#,#.00",
    VISIBLE = 1;


                                ([Measures].[Minimum Selling Price custom1], [Date].[Date YWD].[Week].Members) = 
IIF(
    ISEMPTY
        (
            MIN(PERIODSTODATE([Date].[Date YWD].[(All)], [Date].[Date YWD]), [Measures].[Minimum Minimum Sell Price])
        )
        ,[Item].[Unit Price]
        ,MIN(PERIODSTODATE([Date].[Date YWD].[(All)], [Date].[Date YWD]), [Measures].[Minimum Minimum Sell Price])
    )
;
-- fiscal date

                                ([Measures].[Minimum Selling Price custom1], [Date].[Fiscal Date YPD].[Fiscal Year].Members) = 
IIF(
    ISEMPTY
            (
                MIN(PERIODSTODATE([Date].[Fiscal Date YPD].[(All)], [Date].[Fiscal Date YPD]), [Measures].[Minimum Minimum Sell Price])
            )
            ,[Item].[Unit Price]
            ,MIN(PERIODSTODATE([Date].[Fiscal Date YPD].[(All)], [Date].[Fiscal Date YPD]), [Measures].[Minimum Minimum Sell Price])
    )
;


([Measures].[Minimum Selling Price custom1], [Date].[Fiscal Date YPD].[Accounting Period].Members) = 
IIF(
    ISEMPTY
            (
                MIN(PERIODSTODATE([Date].[Fiscal Date YPD].[(All)], [Date].[Fiscal Date YPD]), [Measures].[Minimum Minimum Sell Price])
            )
            , [Item].[Unit Price]
            , MIN(PERIODSTODATE([Date].[Fiscal Date YPD].[(All)], [Date].[Fiscal Date YPD]), [Measures].[Minimum Minimum Sell Price])
    )
;
```

Comment: What does it show and what do you expect? Can you be more specific here? What do you mean by unit price? Are these members you use on axis? If so, you may use [Item].[Unit Price].CurrentMember.Name.

Comment: the measure calculate the lowest price in sales transaction with relationship to item dimension by ItemID and Date dimension by DateID. The item dimension contains Unit Prices for each item, and if the item has no transaction at all I want it to take Unit Price from Item dimension.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a column value to your Item attribute and get the actual value with MemberValue function. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146082.aspx

Please provide you cube structure in order to explain that practically.